# Python code for ARTXP time series prediction algorithm and ARTXP theory

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, data-mining, time-series

The problem: model evolution of values of a continuous variable over time.

I came through a paper presenting an approach for predicting the next values for a time series. Whereas ARIMA model is more accurate for long term prediction, ARTXP model is preferred to infer the next values.

Microsoft library for Data Mining algorithms implements ARTXP, a variation of Autoregressive Tree model.

How does algorithm works? Do you have a Python implementation for this model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can refer to [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/dmax/publications/dmart-final.pdf), and explications below sum up approach in this paper.

**Model for time series**

Given a temporal sequence of variables, 
[image], a time series is a sequence of values for these variables, [image]. If [image] is a probability distribution or the model, we restrict to models with form

[image]

Model is probabilistic, stationary, and has p-Markov property.

**Autoregressive Tree Model**

First, an *AR model* is of the form

[image]

where [image] is normal distribution with obvious notation.

That is, at each time, probability for a value has mean 'auto-regressively' dependent of the last p values for the series.

An *ART model* is an AR model that is piecewise linear, and therefore can be represented as a tree. Each non leaf is a boolean formula, and each leaf is an AR model.

This is simple: branching along the tree operates depending on past values for the series. Each leaf is then an AR model for predicting the next time series value.

An AR model is a degenerated ART model, where there is one 'boolean' decision node, and one leaf AR model.

Comment: Can you revise the link?